# Extra White space to the right of container class

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

M trying to build a website in Mvc Asp.net Visual Studio. I tried everything, margin:0; padding:0 etc, but my container class is not getting extended to the full width of the page. There is some white space to its right. I included my own stylesheet 'style.css' - bundling it after the default bootstrap.css file in the bundleconfig. Ive used the reset.css file too. 
I dont have much idea about bootstrap responsive feature - @media, so i dont know if any of those in bootstrap.css is causing the problem.
Here's my code:
**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<body>

    <div class="header">
        <div class="container">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <img class="logo" src="~/Content/Images/logo.png" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <h1><span>Kerala</span>-The Experience of a lifetime</h1>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="menu">
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li class="active" role="presentation"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Travel Information</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Seasons</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

**index.cshtml**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<div class="main">
    <div class="container">

    </div>
</div>
```

**style.css**

```
html,body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.header{
    background-color:#1dbbd3;
    width:100%;

    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.container{
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:1px solid black;
}
.header h1{
    font-size:24px;
    font-style:oblique;
    margin-top:0;
    padding-top:0;
}
.header h1 span{
    font-size:64px;
}
.header .row img{
    height:80px;
    width:100px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.header .row .col-md-10{
    color:#1BDA1B;
    text-align:center;
    text-shadow: 4px 4px 4px #aaa;
    /*border:1px solid blue;*/
    margin-left:0;
    padding-bottom:0;
}
.header .menu ul{
    list-style-type:none;
    display:inline-block;
}
.header .menu ul li{
    display:inline-block;
    color:#0d4869;
    margin-right:20px;
}
.header .menu ul li.active{
    background-color:#1BDA1B;
    color:#0d4869;

}
.header .menu li a:hover{
    background-color:#1BDA1B;
}

/**********************Main**********************/
.main{
    background: url(/Content/Images/places8-bekalfort.jpg) no-repeat center center; 
    background-size: cover;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
    height:500px;

}
```

This is the page on the browser:
[image]

The black line on the screen is the border of the container and it clearly has a margin on its right. Please help resolve this issue. Ive been stuck for so long.

Comment: Your code is working for me, not have css bootstrap, do you put your code in [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see the row is fine for what you are trying to achieve. Just remove any custom styling where you have tried to overwrite the bootstrap CSS and then take out the div class="container". The default Bootstrap container restricts your content to 1200px (with padding, 15px with side). It seems to me that you are actually hindering yourself with your custom CSS, when really the div class="container" is most likely your problem.

For full width rather just use div class="row".

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thnku so much for the info on the default bootstrap container. It was definitely an issue with the container, but i cant avoid using it, as it is required for further sections of the project. I solved the problem by setting max-width:1366 (for chrome).